# Changing different button text using only one method

Tags: c#, winforms

Relatively new to C#. I have to make a Tic Tac Toe. I am thinking of using only one method to change my button properties.

This is what I imagine.

```
int count = 0;
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ChangeButton(count);
}
public int ChangeButton(int i)
{
    if(count % 2 == 0)
    {
        // button.text = x
        // i want to be able to change the text of whichever button is clicked
    }
    else
    {
        // button.text = o
    }
    // button.enable = false
    // I want to disable whichever button is clicked
    i++;
    return i;
}
```

I don't know should I do the // parts. Hope you can help me. Thanks!

Comment: [`YourButton.Text = ...`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/how-to-set-the-display-text?view=netdesktop-6.0)

Comment: `i` is already accessible inside the function so you don't have to pass it as a parameter. Pass `sender as Button` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have several buttons all calling the same click event, you can identify the button from the sender parameter:

```
Button btn = sender as Button;
```

Then you can change the text for that button:

```
btn.Text = count++ % 2 == 0 ? "x" : "o";
```

All in your click event:

```
int count = 0;
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = sender as Button;
    btn.Text = count++ % 2 == 0 ? "x" : "o";
    btn.Enabled = false;
}
```